# Strapi : populate from a relation

Tags: strapi

In the example
on the site

[Strapi Docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#relation-media-fields)

To populate specific relations, one or several levels deep, use the LHS bracket notation for fields names in combination with the populate parameter. The qs library (opens new window)is helpful to build complex URLs:

```
const qs = require('qs');
const query = qs.stringify({
  populate: {
    author: {
      populate: ['company'],
    }
  } 
}, {
  encodeValuesOnly: true,
});

await request(`/api/articles?${query}`);
// GET /api/articles?populate[author][populate][0]=company
```

How to fill relationships, two three or more several levels deep?

In my example, I tried

```
/api/regions?populate[cities][populate][0]=holding?spopulate[companies][populate][0]=holdings
```

Comment: const qs = require('qs');
const query = qs.stringify({
  populate: {
    author: {
      populate: {
['company'],
    }
  } 
}, {
  encodeValuesOnly: true,
});

await request(`/api/articles?${query}`);

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845372/strapi-v4-populate-dynamic-zones-media-not-populating). Make sure you're using Strapi v4 and simply install the plugin to the Strapi server.